# Can I separate a string into words by removing spaces? (In python)

Tags: python

(In Python) I want to read a .txt file, take out the string and separate it into variables by separating the string with " ". Maybe this code will help!

```
t = open ("Userlist.txt","r")
    if t.mode == "r":
    y = t.readline
    t.close()
    if " " in y
```

this is where I want the string to be put into 2 variables as there will only be a string like this: USERNAME PASSWORD. Can I separate Username and password (and therefore store them as variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, file.txt contains two words - `USERNAME PASSWORD`

```
   with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        username, password = f.read().split(" ")
        print(username)
        print(password)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split y by " "

```
(name, password) = y.split(' ')
```

Comment: @Harry Ward check out `split()` method for strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html) (scroll to section 4.7.1 and find str.split)

Comment: `str.split()` splits on spaces by default, so the `'  '` is not needed.

Comment: @ChristianDean I know, I've added it to make code more understanable